# why smb-security-mode.nse is not giving proper output?

Tags: samba, smb

When I type (in terminal)

```
nmap -p445 --script smb-protocols \<target\> or nmap -p445 --script smb-security-mode \<target\>
```

the output is

```
Host is up (0.14s latency).

PORT    STATE  SERVICE

445/tcp closed microsoft-ds
```

but it's supposed to give something like

```
smb-security-mode:
|   account_used: guest
|   authentication_level: user
|   challenge_response: supported
|_  message_signing: disabled (dangerous, but default)
```

and the output should be

```
smb-security-mode:
|   account_used: guest
|   authentication_level: user
|   challenge_response: supported
|_  message_signing: disabled (dangerous, but default)
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of the nmap scan shows the SMB port is closed.

> 445/tcp closed microsoft-ds

If the port is closed, there's no way for it to retrieve information about the connection. You must open up the port first (either via the firewall or by actually running an SMB service on the other end) to see results.